# how to extract data from preg_replace

Tags: php, mysql

I wan to be able to get data from a preg_replace function or a str_replace function. For example i want to convert any string beginning with @. But i want to extract that string that begins with @ and put it in my database! So how can i just extract that specific word that begins with @?

Here is my code:

```
$string = "@james is awespome";

$convert = preg_replace('@','<a href="#">@$1</a>','$string');

mysql_query( insert stuff);
```

i want to be able to insert @james or james in the database

Comment: Try `preg_match` instead.

Comment: How is this question related to mysql and mysqli?

Comment: @YourCommonSense im using mysqli_query to insert the data into my database fyi

Comment: @elclanrs i hope it works thats for the answer!

Comment: I bet you are using that inserted info to show on HTML page. Why isn't it tagged with [html] then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) instead:

```
$string = "@james is awespome";
preg_match('/@([A-Za-z0-9_]{1,15})/', $string, $convert); 
//matches @<string of length upto 15 chars>
echo $convert[0];
```

Outputs:

```
@james
```

**[Demo!](https://eval.in/46141)**

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$string = "@james is awespome";
$convert = preg_replace('/(@.*?)\s.*/','$1', $string);
print $convert;
```

Prints `@james`